# Read the memory of my own process without using ReadProcessMemory

Tags: delphi, readprocessmemory, copymemory

Using this way I can get the correct value, but I would like an example of how to read the memory of my own process without using ReadProcessMemory.

```
var
  Modulo : HMODULE;
  Value1, Value2, Read : Cardinal;
  GetWindowTextAAPI: function (hWnd: HWND; lpString: PChar; nMaxCount: integer):integer; stdcall;
begin
  Modulo := GetModuleHandle('user32.dll');
  if (Modulo <> 0) then
  begin
    @GetWindowTextAAPI := GetProcAddress(Modulo, 'GetWindowTextA');
    if (@GetWindowTextAAPI <> nil) then
    begin
      ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, Pointer(@GetWindowTextAAPI), Addr(Value1), 4, Read);
      ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, Pointer(DWORD(@GetWindowTextAAPI)+4), Addr(Value2), 4, Read);
      ShowMessage(
      IntToStr(Value1)
      + ' ' +
      IntToStr(Value2)
      );
    end;
  end;
end;
```

How to Use the function CopyMemory correctly?

Comment: `Assert(PDWORD(@GetWindowTextAAPI)^ = Value1)` . I'm not sure I understand though..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not create a new account for each of [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6365505). Looks like you've interested in API hooking. Is it correct?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz returns Assertion failure.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Thanks, I did not create a new account, I registered because I'm new to Delphi and there are no good forums in my language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do to read memory from your own process. It's what your program already does *all the time*. You certainly don't need `ReadProcessMemory`. Instead, you just dereference a pointer.

Since it doesn't look like you're interested in *calling* the API function, you can start by simplifying your function-pointer declaration:

```
var
  GetWindowTextAAPI: PDWord;
```

Then, assign the pointer and read the value:

```
GetWindowTextAAPI := GetProcAddress(Modulo, 'GetWindowTextA');
Value1 := GetWindowTextAAPI^;
```

Comment: It worked properly, but does not return a correct value if I use + 0x4(BitBltAPI^+4), how to proceed?

Comment: As usual, Delphi requires that your code be syntactically correct.

Comment: My current attempt IntToStr(BitBltAPI^+4) It does not work, how we would be correct?

Comment: *That's* syntactically correct; your previous comment isn't. The expression `BitBltAPI^` gives you the numeric value of the first four bytes of the `BitBlt` function. You're welcome to add 4 to that numeric value, but it's probably not what you intended. Rather, you probably want the numeric value of the *second* four bytes of the function. In your question, you already demonstrated that you know how to add values to pointers. I didn't think I needed to show you again. `PDWord(DWord(BitBltAPI) + 4)^`

Comment: fix'd IntToHex(PDword(dword(BitBltAPI)+4)^,4)